# No dark themes available in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just created an example application with Android Studio. Now I want to change the default theme from light to dark. In the styles.xml the following options are available. None of them seems to do the trick.
How can I make use of the dark themes?

[image: Themes]

Answer (score 0):

Even if you apply that in your `styles.xml` your default mode will be light. Only if you switch it by calling `AppcompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES)` for dark mode, and `AppcompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)` for light mode in your Application class or wherever you need this functionality to change themes. Also, notice that you will have problems if you have already set custom colors, therefore you will need to files for colors: `colors.xml` in values folder and `colors.xml` in values-night folder. 
For more, you can check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme), or my [article](https://medium.com/@stavro96/some-quick-notes-on-dark-mode-ac936d972480). More modes:

```
//dark mode
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)

//light mode
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

//asking if dark mode is on:
AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES

//asking if light mode is on:
AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight** for dark theme and more details please prefer the below link

https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.